# Ubuntu 18.04 disable tablet style slide up to unlock

Tags: 18.04, gnome, lock-screen

Once the desktop locks due to inactivity, an overlay is displayed that must be "slid up" before being able to log in again.

I'd like do disable that overlay using any key press, or remove it entirely.